# Running ngrok console application as a process from C# does not work

Tags: c#, .net, process, console, ngrok

Dear Stack Overflow Community,

I'm trying to communicate with the Ngrok console using C #. Unfortunately "StartInfo.Arguments" does not work. For example, if I write **"StartInfo.Arguments ="** ngrok in the c# code", the ngrok help text does not appear, but" ERROR: Unrecognized command: ngrok "in the log. But if I open the console myself and write in" ngrok "it works.

```
private void startServer()

        Process compiler = new Process();
        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "ngrok.exe";
        compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"ngrok\"";
        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        compiler.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        compiler.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using "ngrok" as argument. That is the same as you would write `ngrok.exe ngrok` in the console. The command is not recognized by ngrok. Try to use proper arguments for example `compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "http 80";` or just leave it blank. If you want to use ngrok with the port 80 over http your code has to look like that:

```
private void startServer()

    Process compiler = new Process();
    compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "ngrok.exe";
    compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "http 80";
    compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    compiler.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

    compiler.WaitForExit();
}
```